Google sheet's Drawing Dynamic data
I have Google Sheets named 'ABC' and 'CDE'. I want to display the data from cell A1 of 'ABC' in a text box on 'CDE'. Is it possible using Google Apps Script or any other solution? I have searched for a while but haven't found anything useful.

I have tried it using Apps scrip but does not seems to work anything
function updateDrawing() {
  var cdeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CDE'); 
  var abcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ABC'); 
  var value = abcSheet.getRange('P14').getValue(); 
  var drawings = cdeSheet.getDrawings(); // Get all drawings in the DASHBOARD sheet
  if (drawings.length > 0) {
    var shape = drawings[0]; // Assuming you want to update the first drawing
    shape.asTextBox().setText(value); // Set the text to the value from Apex!B14
  }
}


this code is wrong as it will fetch all drawings
also it's not working for any drawing

As far as I know Google Apps Script doesn’t provide direct support for fetching or updating the content of a drawing. Unfortunately, the .getDrawings() function only allows limited interaction with drawings. If you are open for other workarounds we can use it to display via html or Floating window. If not, kindly provide your expected result so I can adjust my response accordingly.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

BTW, asTextBox() what is your reference for this command?

.getDrawings() function only allows limited interaction with drawings
As far as I know Google Apps Script doesn’t provide direct support for fetching or updating the content of a drawing. Unfortunately,

The .getDrawings() function only allows limited interaction with drawings.
The .getDrawings() function doesn’t support setting text for drawings, and text boxes aren't accessible the way ranges or cells.

If you are open to other workarounds we can use it to display via HTML or Floating window. If not, kindly provide your expected result so I can adjust my response accordingly.
Reference

getDrawings()

